# jquery rotate callback not called if image not rotated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code rotating an image and then moving it - which works fine unless the image does not rotate - meaning the current angle of the image is equal to the angle it should rotate to - in this case the callback function is not called, so there is no animation. The rotate function comes from a plugin.

```
$("#Ship" + shipID).rotate({
                    duration: 500,
                    angle: $(this).getRotateAngle(),
                    animateTo: parseInt(rotate),
                    callback: function () {
                        $("#" + shipID).animate({
                            left: parseInt(moveX),
                            top: parseInt(moveY)
                        }, 500, function () {                            
                        });    
                    }
                })
```

If the animate function is written after the rotate - then the rotate and animation happen at the same time.

I don't think I can force the callback as I would have to edit the plugin (but im not sure about that). Is there a way to write the animate after the rotate, but wait for rotate to finish? I guess one way would be is to use delay, but is there a more proper way?

Comment: Don't use the `animateTo` in the plugin's parameters, and instead execute an `$.animate()` in the `callback` of the plugin?

Comment: Ok, looks like I jumped the gun here. You already are executing your animation in the `callback`. So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: callback does not run if the image is already pointing in the direction it should rotate to

Comment: So you're saying that the code in the callback is executing at the same time that the `animateTo` is running?

Comment: Ok, what plugin are you using? This must be happening this way due to how the plugin was written.

Comment: So lets say it should move North and it is pointing East: it will rotate from E to N and then move. If the image is already pointing North and should rotate to North - then no actual animation happens so the callback funciton is not calles

Comment: Ok, now I understand...

Comment: I guess I should just check if the current angle and destination are equal and if yes, then skip the rotate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the rotation before you try to execute anything with the plugin. I'm not exactly sure how you'll check the current rotation, but:

```
var currentRotation = $("#Ship" + shipID).getRotateAngle();
if(currentRotation != rotate) {
    $("#Ship" + shipID).rotate({
        duration: 500,
        angle: $(this).getRotateAngle(),
        animateTo: parseInt(rotate),
        callback: function () {
            $(this).rotate({
                animateTo: rotate
            });
            $("#" + shipID).animate({
                left: parseInt(moveX),
                top: parseInt(moveY)
            }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

Depending on your exact setup and how the plugin works, you may need to check your `currentRotation` inside of the plugin method. Or, you may need to set up some events to execute the `if` statement. Again, this would depend on how you're brinding this all together (how do you know when you want something to rotate?)